# I have installed ubuntu latest version i.e. 16.04 LTS, but wifi is not working

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I have already tried installing `rtlwifi-new-dkms` and `dkms-2.2.0.3 2ubuntu11.all.deb` and also tried to disable security in boot option.
My laptop is HP and I don't have ethernet cable and no internet.

Comment: What is the wireless adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue Resolved.**

1. Disable Secure Boot from BIOS/UEFI.
2. Then while installing Ubuntu make sure that you check ***install essential drivers*** checkbox, while doing so Wifi must be enabled and connected.
3. Install Ubuntu, once completed restart the system.
4. Wifi will work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

First connect through LAN to your Laptop and than Go to System setting of your Ubuntu 16.04 click on software update go to 5th tab(Additional Driver) and select the driver you want to install here it will show your wireless driver too also  you can check on other software tabs too. it will automatically install all the drivers.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue a few days ago. Here is what to do:

1. Connect to the Internet via an Ethernet Cable(no workaround around this, I'm afraid). Use a friends Connection if needed.
2. Disable Secure Boot from BIOS/UEFI.
3. Install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package via `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: That's the big issue i don't have ethenet cable and also my friend doesn't have. can i get the package in local and then through pendrive i can copy to my system and i can run any command to package. if  yes, then can you please tell the commands and step by step procedure for the same.

Comment: do you have access to an Internet Cafe near your area? Or you can use USB tethering from your android device if you have one to install the package using your phones internet

Comment: I have vodafone 4g dongle, i have tried to install. it is saying that it is installed but don't known how it will work

Comment: I have followed all the instruction given in read text -- how to install airtel in ubuntu but it is not working

Comment: I don't know much about the specifics of Dongles I'm afraid, but if they aren't working.. You should try using your Phone instead.

Comment: how to use phone..? can i use phone wifi..? please tell the procedures

Comment: Follow the tethering via USB section of: http://www.junauza.com/2012/07/how-to-tether-android-smartphone-to.html

Comment: Ayush Can i install bcmwl-kernel-source as a debian package from other machine then  then install that package by command in my pc by taking that package in my system

Comment: I doubt it, as the bcmwl-kernel-source might need to install other dependant packages

Comment: Ayush i got ethernet can you please tell i have connect through ether net and it is searching . but not connecting .? is there any procedure to connect with ethernet

Comment: Not sure, try googling it.

Comment: Its also not working try after googling it is showing connection established but  still internet is not working .

Comment: Thanks @Ayush It really helped though i haven't use ethernet options.