# Ubuntu- no wifi even with secure boot turned off

Tags: boot, wireless, secure-boot

I can't get my wifi running in ubuntu. I have secure boot turned off, tried tips from other posts and still nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: please provide your hardware and software information

Comment: "tried tips from other posts" could you please list what you've done so far?

Comment: I have tried:
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
sudo apt-get install rfkill
sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 up
service network-manager restart
Remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
Re-install bcmwl-kernel-source and the kernel header:
sudo apt-get install linux-generic bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: Try this... https://askubuntu.com/questions/827445/i-have-installed-ubuntu-latest-version-i-e-16-04-lts-but-wifi-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, Software & Updates, Additional Drivers, and select use next to the wifi drivers, if you're not sure, then select it next to everything. This requires some sort of internet to install drivers though. Another thing to do if it is a fresh install anyway, install ubuntu again and be sure to select install third party software.